# indentify url to send http commands from code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-request

i'm having an weird problem, my project have a login page, that's working, but i have to use this login page using http shell commands like:

```
curl -v http://google.com/
```

My problem is, how can i identify the URL to send the request from the source code?
Follow the source code:

```
def create
  if request.post?
    if session[:account] = Account.authenticate(params[:account][:username], params[:account][:password])
      flash[:message] = "Login successful"
      redirect_to :controller => "items", :action => "index"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Login unsuccessful"
      redirect_to :controller => "login", :action => "create"
    end
  end
end
```

If i try sent a request like this:

```
curl -d "account(username)=guilherme&account(password)=123456" http://localhost:3000/login
```

I have this response:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have
>   expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating
>   nil.[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did not really understand your question, but i think that the curl line you posted should use brackets instead of parenthesis

```
curl -d "account[username]=guilherme&account[password]=123456" http://localhost:3000/login
```

i am asking myself what you are going to do with this, because you are not going to be able to keep the session-cookies with this approach?!

Comment: I have to send a request from an android application to my ruby application, them i have to send the authentication to my login page by a http request, but i got an error, not really an error, but a problem, when i send this curl request i don't get the authentication token, only the cookie session, do you know how to do this?